# Solving double integral $\int _0^1\int _1^x\frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t \ \sqrt{x}} \ \mathrm dt \ \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

How to solve the following integral?
$$\int _0^1\int _1^x\frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t \sqrt{x}} \ \mathrm dt \ \mathrm dx$$

I tried to change the variables by using subsitution $(1+t) = u$ and $t \sqrt{x} = v$ but it didn't simplify the integral.

Any hints?

Comment: hint: swap the limits so that $ t \leq x \leq 1$, and do the $x$ integral first. 

You get: $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(t+1)}{t} - t^{1/2}\ln(t+1)dt$

Comment: Your limit is $1 \leq t \leq x$, where $x \leq 1$, double check it!

Comment: The original format of the question is like this: Evaluate $\int _0^1\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}}dx\:$ where f(x) = $\int _1^x\frac{ln\left(1+t\right)}{t}dt\:$ so I interpreted it as a double integral, is that ok?

Comment: yeah that is definitely the way to go, if $x \in [0,1]$ then you've got $t$ from $1$ to $x<1$, you can always add a minus sign in and swap it round. It isn't a crucial learning point tbf

Comment: i am having trouble solving $\int _0^1\frac{ln\left(1+t\right)}{t}dt\:$ , can't seem to find a suitable substitution?

Comment: It cannot be written in the form of elementary functions, put it into wolfram alpha

Answer (score 4):

Start with changing the order of the integration

$$\int_0^1\int_1^x\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t\sqrt{x}}dtdx=\int_0^1\int_t^0\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t\sqrt{x}}dxdt=-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{t}}dt$$

$$\overset{\sqrt{t}=u}{=}-4\int_0^1\ln(1+u^2)du\overset{IBP}{=}-4\ln2+8\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}du$$

$$=-4\ln2+8\left(1-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\boxed{8-2\pi-4\ln2}$$

and this way we avoided using any special function.

Answer (score 2):

As noted before the inner integral is not doable using a suitable substitution. Anyway, this is not a real problem by accepting the usage of special functions, in particular by invoking the [Dilogarithm Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html). Doing so one can get back to elementary integrals yielding the result.

We shall proceed in the following manner
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_1^x\frac{\log(1+t)}t{\rm d}t\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt x}&=\int_0^1[-{\rm Li}_2(-t)]_1^x\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt x}\\
&=\int_0^1\left[-{\rm Li}_2(-x)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right]\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt x}\\
&=\left[2\sqrt x\left(-{\rm Li}_2(-x)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)\right]_0^1-2\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{\sqrt x}{\rm d}x\\
&=-4\int_0^1\log(1+x^2){\rm d}x\\
&=-4[x\log(1+x^2)]_0^1+8\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}{\rm d}x\\
&=-4\log(2)+8\int_0^11-\frac1{1+x^2}{\rm d}x\\
&=-4\log(2)+8-8[\arctan(x)]_0^1
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\int_0^1\int_1^x\frac{\log(1+t)}t{\rm d}t\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt x}~=~8-2\pi-4\log(2)$$

Note, however, that the Dilogarithm is only used in between to make some calculations look prettier and is almsot immediately removed again by via IBP. Therefore, it might be possible to dodge the utilisation of the Dilogarithm by simply denoting the intermediate anti-derivative as, lets say, $F(t)$ and observe that the value of $F(t)$ at $1$ is $0$ and at $0$ is defined (as $\sqrt x$ is $0$ at this point). The decision is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

From Wolfram Alpha $\int _1^x\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} \ dt=-Li_2(-x)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$, so it doesn't have a 'regular' function as an aswer.

Also the final answer is $-1.055$